# JSONObject throws exception

Tags: java, android

I have this section of code (note that `responseBody` truly comes from a web server).

```
public JSONObject getObj(){
    String responseBody = '[{"zip":"56601","city":"Bemidji","state":"MN","county":"Beltrami","dist":"0.14802"},{"zip":"56619","city":"Bemidji","state":"MN","county":"Beltrami","dist":"3.98172"}]';

    JSONObject response = null;

    try{
        response = new JSONObject(responseBody);
    }catch(JSONException ex){
        Logger.getLogger(Http.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    return response;
}
```

I don't understand why JSONObject is throwing an exception. What is making it do that?

Comment: What exception do you get?  (Please don't say JSONException, inspect the instance)

Comment: I don't know, I can't figure out how to inspect it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a JSONArray with a JSONObject in it not a JSONObject.

see this link:
http://www.w3schools.com/json/json_syntax.asp

Comment: Values may be any mix of JSONObjects, JSONArrays, Strings, Booleans, Integers, Longs, Doubles or NULL. Source [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html)

Comment: yes inside a JSONObject there can be any value. but this is not a JSONObject to start with

Comment: @Mr.Me changed to this: `response = new JSONArray(responseBody);`

Comment: You response have a broken link.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
public static JSONArray getObj(){
    String responseBody = "[{\"zip\":\"56601\",\"city\":\"Bemidji\",\"state\":\"MN\",\"county\":\"Beltrami\",\"dist\":\"0.14802\"},{\"zip\":\"56619\",\"city\":\"Bemidji\",\"state\":\"MN\",\"county\":\"Beltrami\",\"dist\":\"3.98172\"}]";

    JSONArray response = null;

    try{
        return new JSONArray(responseBody);
    }catch(JSONException ex){
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    return response;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're getting an exception becuase you are trying to create a `JSONObject` - which is enclosed in the {} - from something that is a `JSONArray` - enclosed in the []. If you look at your repsonse body you will see it is enclosed in square brackets [] and is a JSONArray.

To get the individual objects out you need to (1) create a JSONArray; (2) create a seperate JSONObject for the value you want; (3) return that object. For example, to return the first value in the responseBody:

```
try{
JSONArray responseArray = new JSONArray(responseBody);
return responseArray.getJSONObject(0);
} catch (JSONException e) {
    Log.e("JSON", e.toString());
}
```

To get information out of a specific JSONObject returned in the above example, e.g. the zip code, you would then use:

```
JSONObject a = getObj(); 
String zip = a.getString("zip");
```

Iterating over the array is just as easy. Because JSONObjects are extracted from the JSONArray by their index number, just use a `for loop` to pull each object out. You can then process the internal strings as you like.